# Trouble testing Meteor example

Tags: meteor

i've installed as per instructions on the site,
but all I get when I try the leaderboard example is a :

"This webpage has a redirect loop" page from Chrome
The url has changed to localhost:3000/Users/myname/

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: did you ever solve this or find any resources about specifics?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with a space in my username,
when I moved the project out of the Users folder, 
it works like a charm.